# Late MBP 2015 vs MBP 2016 gaming experience (WoW, HotS)

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, mac-pro, games

I fully understand these machines are not designed for gaming at all, but I was wondering if you guys can tell me approximate FPS for these games:

- World of Warcraft
- Heroes of the Storm

with let's say low-medium details with somewhat better resolution (not needed to be Full HD). What will be the difference in performance and FPS between a MacBook Pro 2015 (Iris 6100), MacBook Pro 2016 (Iris 540) and MacBook Pro 2016 (Iris 550)?

Comment: Do you own these MBP models and games? I ask because there are ways to monitor the FPS rate and it's easy enough to explain that in an answer. Otherwise, It's going to be hard for someone to answer this unless they have access to those exact configurations of MBP and the two games. I suppose this info _could_ be gleaned from various online reviews, but that'd be a long shot.

Comment: No, I don't have these devices :( I tried to look for this on the internet.. mostly they're presenting different games - which is somewhat acceptable for me, as I know they games I mentioned are less demanding - but I want to make sure. I was hoping that someone with base 2016 model or base 2015 model would download and install at least one the games and just check how much FPS can squeeze out of it. That's job for like 1 hour (including downloading) :)